# Randomly grab 3 items from an array, where the 3rd item can be a “restaurant" but does not have to be

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I apologize for the poorly written title. I was not sure how exactly to write it. I have an array. I need to randomly grab three items from the array. Only one item can be a "restaurant" and the restaurant can ONLY ever go in the third position.

Let me explain with an example. here is a sample array

```
el 1 - restaurant = false
el 2 - restaurant = true
el 3 - restaurant = true
el 4 - restaurant = false
el 5 - restaurant = false
el 6 - restaurant = false
el 7 - restaurant = true
el 8 - restaurant = false
el 9 - restaurant = false
```

My current code loops through this array and randomly grabs three items. Positions 1 and 2 can **NEVER** have a restaurant in them so they have to be taken from the items with the restaurant property set to *false*. The 3rd position **can** have a restaurant but I don't want it to **always** be a restaurant.

Here is my current code:

```
const amountOfLocations = 3

// have list of locations
// shuffle it
for (let i = locations.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [locations[i], locations[j]] = [locations[j], locations[i]];
}

let selectedLocations = locations.slice(0, amountOfLocations)
```

My initial thought is I need to grab only 2 items from this current loop instead of 3, then using the original array remove these two items and shuffle the array up again to randomly grab one more item which will then be placed in the 3rd position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could continue using the shuffle method so you don't end up selecting duplicates like with plain random indexing, then you just extract the first element from the shuffled array and call it "third". Then you filter out non-restaurants (and slice the first index before because we've already selected it) and select any 2 elements:

```
for (let i = locations.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
  [locations[i], locations[j]] = [locations[j], locations[i]];
}

let third = locations[0];
let [first, second] = locations.slice(1).filter(l => !l.restaurant);
let selectedLocations = [first, second, third];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a whole loop. randomly select an element — if you are not choosing the third element and a restaurant is picked, don’t save the choice and let the whole loop run again (until you have three elements).

Or

Make a temporary array without the restaurants in it, and then randomly select from that array twice. Then randomly select from the normal array. If it matches one of the two you already have, then get it again (use a while loop).

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
    var array1 = [
     {'restaurant': true},
     {'restaurant': false},
     {'restaurant': false},
     {'restaurant': true},
     {'restaurant': false},
     {'restaurant': true},
     {'restaurant': false},
     {'restaurant': false},
     {'restaurant': false},
     {'restaurant': false},
     {'restaurant': true}
    ];

    var array2 = array1.filter((v) => {
      return v.restaurant === false;
    }).slice(0, 2);
    array2.push(array1[Math.floor(Math.random() * array1.length)]);

console.log(array2);
```

Here's a link to fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/90gda2sb/

Comment: I really appreciate the answer but I am going to go with the answer from Toribio since his stayed inline with my current code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const third = shuffledArray[0]
const [first, second] = first two no-resturant item in shuffledArray.slice(1)
```